# Replace the default copy constructor with a template copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a template class C. I want such a template copy constructor that it will resize the data array according to the size of the other class.

The following is a simple example. It works fine. However, notice that `Constructor 2` and `Constructor 3` are so similar, I am wondering whether it is possible to merge them as one?

Also, if I simple remove `Constructor 3`, then `C<int> c3( c1 )` won't call `Constructor 2`, but will rather call a default copy constructor added by the compiler. This will result in the memory not being allocated properly.

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
public:
    T* val; 
    int size; 
public:

    C( int s = 0 ) {
        cout << "Constructor 1" << endl; 
        size = s; 
        val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
    } 

    template<class T2>
    C( const C<T2>& c2 ) {
        cout << "Constructor 2" << endl; 
        size = c2.size; 
        val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
    } 

    C( const C<T>& c2 ) {
        cout << "Constructor 3" << endl; 
        size = c2.size; 
        val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
    } 

    ~C() {
        cout << "~C()" << endl; 
        delete[] val; 
        val = nullptr; 
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    C<int>   c1( 5 );
    C<float> c2( c1 );  
    C<int>   c3( c1 ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above function:

```
Constructor 1
Constructor 2
Constructor 3
~C()
~C()
~C()
```

Comment: You can use constructor delegation in C++11, or a member function (helper) that performs this initialization.

Comment: Assuming you want to do something useful with the memory you're allocating, what is constructor 2 going to do with the objects from the source type?

Comment: Do you intend to perform a copy of the elements of `c2.val` in those constructors?

Comment: @dyp Yes, I do want the data as well. But I didn't mention it in the post above. But that won't be a problem.

Comment: You could implement Constructor 3 in terms of a delegating constructor. It's new in C++11.

Comment: @Praetorian, I simply want to copy the data over.

Comment: @YuchenZhong And what if the size of `T2` is greater than that of `T`? How are you going to make the array of `T2` objects fit into the array of `T` objects that you've allocated? Or are you relying on `T2` to be convertible to `T`?

Comment: @Praetorian Yes. I am relying on that T2 to be convertible to T. For example from `int` to `double` and things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
template<class T2>
C( const C<T2>& c2 ) {
    cout << "Constructor 2" << endl; 
    size = c2.size; 
    val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
} 

C( const C<T>& c2 ) {
    cout << "Constructor 3" << endl; 
    size = c2.size; 
    val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
}
```

by

```
template<class T2>
C( const C<T2>& c2, int dummy) {
    cout << "Constructor 2" << endl; 
    size = c2.size; 
    val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
}

template<class T2>
C( const C<T2>& c2 ) : C(c2, 0) {}

C( const C<T>& c2 ) : C(c2, 0) {}
```

**Update**

You can just use:

```
C( int s = 0 ) {
    cout << "Constructor 1" << endl; 
    size = s; 
    val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
} 

template<class T2>
C( const C<T2>& c2 ) : C(c2.size) {}

C( const C<T>& c2 ) : C(c2.size) {}
```

and not need the second constructor.

Comment: It is not so elegant. However, it seems this is the only way to wark around this.

Comment: Typically, you use a special private class as the type for the dummy and make that ctor private. This prevents overloading issues (users of the class calling that ctor inadvertently).

Comment: Looks a lot like how you overload the postfix inc/dec operators, by adding int to the signature. As far as the update, this works here; but OP did refer to these as copy constructors, perhaps the code to do the actual copy or type conversion was omitted, in which case T2 must be known in the common code.

Comment: @Apriori I didn't quite follow where you were heading with the last statement in your comment.

Comment: @R Sahu: Lets say you are copying a `C<int>` from a `C<float>` and the copy/conversion constructors actually copy (and convert in this case) the elements from the source container. That is if you have a `C<float> source;` containing {1.2f, 3.9f, 5.5f} and you create the object `C<int> dest(source);` you probably expect it to have the values {1, 3, 5} as the contained floats have been converted to ints. OPs code just allocates the space to copy into, but never copies. To perform the conversion you need to know the type you are copying from, you cant's just copy the bytes.

Comment: @Apriori Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense now. For that usage, my code from my updated section won't work but code from the original answer would.

Answer (score 0):

One would like to implement this with a C++11 delegating constructor. However due to ambiguity in if template paramaters are to the class or to the constructor, this is not possible in a straightforward manner. As a workaround one can factor out the common code into a helper function.

something like:

```
    template<class T2>
    C( const C<T2>& c2 ) {
        Copy<T2>(c2);
    } 

    C( const C<T>& c2 ) {
        Copy<T>(c2);
    }

private:
    template<class T2>
    void Copy( const C<T2>& c2 ) {
        cout << "Constructor 2" << endl; 
        size = c2.size; 
        val = ( size ) ? new T[size] : nullptr; 
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure that the second constructor is delegating to itself. Edit: [Yep, it is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c052b789d02eddef). Interesting that clang detects that and throws an error, while gcc segfaults.

Comment: @Praetorian: Yes you are correct. I was trying to get the general idea out. But yes, it doesn't resolve the template parameter as one would like. btw, in VS you get "success" building unless you treat warnings as errors. I updated the answer with something a little different that doesn't change the second ctor's signature.